# mysql return count = 0 without joins using group by

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
Image
| ImageId | UserId | SourceId |
| 1       | 1      | 1        |
| 2       | 1      | 2        |
| 3       | 2      | 1        |
| 4       | 2      | 2        |
| 5       | 3      | 1        |
| 6       | 3      | 1        |
| 7       | 3      | 1        |
| 8       | 3      | 1        |
| 9       | 3      | 1        |
```

I then have a query:

```
SELECT UserId, IFNULL( COUNT( ImageId ) , 0 ) AS ImageCount, SourceId
FROM Image
GROUP BY UserId, SourceId
```

When I do the query, I get

```
| UserId | SourceId | ImageCount
| 1      | 1        | 1
| 1      | 2        | 1
| 2      | 1        | 1
| 1      | 2        | 1
| 3      | 1        | 5
```

However, the one row that I do NOT get back (which I want) is:

```
| 3      | 1        | 0
```

How do I go about fetching the row, even if the count is 0?

All of the questions I've seen have had to deal with joins (usually left joins) but as this doesn't require a join I'm a little confused as to how to go about this.

Comment: `UserId=3 and SourceId=1` is already aggregated as count 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does require a `left join` and a bit more.  You need to start with all possible combinations, then use `left join` to bring in the existing values:

```
SELECT u.UserId, COUNT(i.ImageId ) AS ImageCount, s.SourceId
FROM (select distinct UserId from Image) u cross join
     (select distinct SourceId from Image) s left join
     Image i
     on i.UserId = u.UserId and i.SourceId = s.SourceId
GROUP BY u.UserId, s.SourceId;
```

The `count()` will return `0` if there are no matches.  There is no need for an `if`, `coalesce`, or `case` statement.

What this does is create every possible combination of `UserId` and `SourceId` (based on the values in the `Image` table).  It then uses a `left outer join` to connect back to the image.  What does this do?  Well, for existing records, it actually does nothing.  But for combinations that don't appear in the table, it will add a new row with `u.UserId`, `s.SourceId`, and `NULL` in the other fields.  This is the basis for the final aggregation.

Comment: This is absolutely correct and I will mark it as so when the timer is up.  However, can you go into a little more depth as to HOW this query works, specifically why the `select distinct`, and the `cross join`?